# Remove Thread and category column in log4j html log

Tags: java, logging, log4j

i am generating html format log output using log4j, but i want to output only   Time Level and Message Column in it.
how to format it in properties file?? do we need any things to be coded also??
please help.

```
log4j.appender.HA=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.HA.File=c://Test_Log/Test_Log.html
log4j.appender.HA.layout=org.apache.log4j.HTMLLayout
log4j.appender.HA.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
```

help me...
thanks all

Answer (score 1):

HTML layout doesn't look like it has a ConversionPattern

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html):

- `%c` is the category
- `%t` is the thread info

Remove those from your pattern:

```
log4j.appender.HA.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r %-5p %x - %m%n
```