# How to remove columns from Log4j HTML Log

Tags: java, logging, log4j

There are six columns (Time, Thread, Level, Category, File:Line and Message) in log4j HTML log. But I don't want all of these columns in my log. Suppose, I need only **Time**, **Level** and **Message** columns in my HTML log. How I can do this in log4j?

N.B: I found a similar question, but it had no solutions.

[Remove Thread and category column in log4j html log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6923247/remove-thread-and-category-column-in-log4j-html-log)

Answer (score 0):

Create a different appender

```
<appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <param name="Target" value="System.out" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p: %c - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

Change this

```
<param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p: %c - %m%n" />
```

1. Log message   -> m
2. Date and Time -> d
3. level         -> p
4. Category name -> c

Comment: As I have to use HTMLLayout, how can I use ConversionPattern?

Comment: are you using .xml or .properties file for Log4j configuration and can you share it.

Comment: I am using properties file.

`log4j.properties:

log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, HTML

log4j.appender.HTML=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.HTML.File=log.html

log4j.appender.HTML.layout=org.apache.log4j.HTMLLayout
log4j.appender.HTML.layout.Title=Application Logs
log4j.appender.HTML.layout.LocationInfo=true
log4j.appender.HTML.Threshold=DEBUG`

Comment: You are using HTML layout, it does not support conversionpattern. What you can do is write a custom HTMLLayout class Extend the Log4J HTMLLayout class and replace the format() method.